# Initialization of unit-test in PyDev?

Tags: python, eclipse, unit-testing, eclipse-plugin, pydev

I am unit-testing my python code in eclipse using PyDev unit-testing. I right click on the appropriate file and select *Run As -> Python unit-test*. Concerning this plugin I have a few questions:

1. Is there a way to have a **setUpClass** method that is being executed before any other test within this class? Currently I am only able to get **setUp** working, which is called before any test of the class
2. Is there a way to have a global initialization that is being called before any test is executed? Something like **setUpModule** which I am also not able to get running using PyDev unit-testing.

Thanks in advance for any answer and comment^^
Cherio Woltan

**Example:**

```
class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):

  @classmethod
  def setUpClass(self):
      print "Setup"    

  def test1(self):
      print "Test1"
  def test2(self):
      print "Test2"
```

If I run this with *Run As -> Python unit-test* the *setUpClass* method is not being called.

Comment: I tried this on some of my code and `setUpClass()` / `tearDownClass()` execute when the script is run with 'Python Run' but not when using 'Python unit-test'. I think this is a bug with PyDev, and I have added a [tracker artifact](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3277997&group_id=85796&atid=577329) for it.

Comment: Just for completeness, this was an issue in PyDev and has been fixed for version 2.0.1 (already available in the current nightly build).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a PyDev bug, and has been fixed in 2.0.1.

`setUpModule()`, `tearDownModule()`, `setUpClass()`, and `tearDownClass()` are not run in the 'Python unit-test' run configuration due to the bug in PyDev 2.0.0 and earlier. In 2.0.1 they run correctly in the 'Python unit-test' and 'Python Run' configurations. I tested it myself to verify.

Comment: Just for the record: After the bug fix it works on my machine as well!

Comment: I'm having PyDev 2.1.0 and I cannot get setUpModule() working. Am I correct that setUpModule() shall be execute at the beginning, before the test cases? Where shall it be in code? As a global function in the module? Does it depend on selected grammar (Python 2.6)?

Comment: @sumid `setUpModule()` was introduced with the new `unittest` module in Python 2.7. It is possible to use the new unit test functionality in Python 2.6 by using `import unittest2`, but I don't think there is a way to get PyDev to recognize that you want to run your tests that way. You may want to bring this issue up with the PyDev developers. See [this related thread](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/forums/forum/293649/topic/4543888) on the PyDev users forum.

Answer (score 5):

OK I'll give this a shot: I use Pydev and have been exploring using "nosetests" to launch tests so it's sort of relevant. My solution is a total hack, but does seem to work when saying "Debug as UnitTest" from within PyDev:

```
print "before any tests (global) just once..."
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
   class_setup_called = False
   def __init__(self, test_name):
      unittest.TestCase.__init__(self, test_name)
      if not self.__class__.class_setup_called:
          self.setUpClass()
          self.__class__.class_setup_called = True
   @staticmethod
   def setUpClass():
      print "before first test only..."
   def setUp(self):
      print "before each test..."
```

Unfortunately this will not work when using nosetests, but it does work when running from pydev. I'm guessing that nosetests is coded to instantiate test objects before each test method is run, in which case your init method would suffice.

I can't say enough nice things about nosetests:

- support for exceptions and timed
  tests.
- support for annotation "attribution".
- integration with profile, coverage and xunit reporting of results.
- recursive discovery and attributed execution of test cases.

examples:

```
import unittest
@raises(TypeError)          
def test_forexceptions(self): 
    pass

@attr('benchmark')
@timed(5.0)
def test_benchmark(self):
    pass # do something real slow and run nosetests --with-profile -a benchmark
```

#### Additional

On further investigation if you are using nosetests then it has you covered, see "http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/1.0.0/writing_tests.html".

You can have:

package level teardowns: (these live in package level init scripts)

```
def setup_package()
def teardown_package()
```

module level teardowns:

```
def setup_module()
def teardown_module()
```

class level:

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls): pass
    @classmethod
    def teardown_class(cls): pass
```

and test method level:

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self): pass
    def tearDown(cls): pass
```

I like to use the the "setup_" names as it nicely delineates the nose specific entry points. I've verified these work nicely when run from nosetests via the command line. But they do NOT run from Pydev "run as unit test...". A potential solution may be writing a pydev plugin that uses nose to run the tests... perhaps someone has one? You could combine my hack with the nose ones calling common module functions to do the actual work. Ideally our **init**() would be aware of being launched from Pydev somehow.

Comment: Hi Carl,
this is an interesting hack and does exactly what I was asking for. Too bad that this approach is not compatible with the nosetest framework.

Comment: Hey Carl,
thx again for your great answer! If I can find the time, maybe I'll have a look at the source code of PyDev to find out what is going on in there. Until then, I'll use your 'hack'.

Answer (score 2):

### Edit: Summary

Stepping through your test case with the debugger, it look's like this is a limitation of PyDev's test runner not supporting `setUpClass()`, at least not with 1.6.5, which I'm using.

Maybe this will be fixed in v2.0 of PyDev, but in the meantime, I think we will have to [stick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336626/giving-parameters-into-testcase-from-suite-in-python/5381422#5381422) to using `__init__()` instead, as [CarlS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430707/initialization-of-unit-test-in-pydev/5480499#5480499) suggests.

#### Details

The PyDev 1.6.5 PyDevTestSuite class uses:

```
def run(self, result):
    for index, test in enumerate(self._tests):
        if result.shouldStop:
            break
        test(result)

        # Let the memory be released! 
        self._tests[index] = None

    return result
```

which is very similar to TestSuite.run() in python 2.6, whereas TestSuite.run() in python 2.7.1's unittest does rather more:

```
def run(self, result, debug=False):
    topLevel = False
    if getattr(result, '_testRunEntered', False) is False:
        result._testRunEntered = topLevel = True

    for test in self:
        if result.shouldStop:
            break

        if _isnotsuite(test):
            self._tearDownPreviousClass(test, result)
            self._handleModuleFixture(test, result)
            self._handleClassSetUp(test, result)
            result._previousTestClass = test.__class__

            if (getattr(test.__class__, '_classSetupFailed', False) or
                getattr(result, '_moduleSetUpFailed', False)):
                continue

        if not debug:
            test(result)
        else:
            test.debug()

    if topLevel:
        self._tearDownPreviousClass(None, result)
        self._handleModuleTearDown(result)
    return result
```

### Old answer

I suspect this may be down to the version of Python that is being referenced.

If you check Window > Preferences > PyDev > Interpreter - Python and look at which Python Interpretter is being used, you may well find that it is pre v2.7 where, if I remember correctly, setUpClass was introduced.

Reference a newer version of python and I suspect your tests will work as is.

Comment: Hi Mark,
thx for your answer, but I am using Python 2.7 and it is also selected as the python interpreter. So this seems not to be the problem.
cherio Woltan

Comment: FYI I tested v2.0 of PyDev and the problem is not fixed.

Comment: Thanks for checking Series8217. I didn't think it was worth a bug report though, as it feels more like a feature request.

Comment: I filed a [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3277997&group_id=85796&atid=577329) for it and the developers fixed the problem right away. If you update PyDev from the [nightly update site](http://pydev.org/nightly) you'll be able to download the latest version with the fix (version 2.0.1).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `unittest.main()`, which automatically goes through all your test classes and individual tests, you can load the tests from each class separately and execute them at your discretion, including before each class test the necessary initializations. You can precede all that with some global initialization as well. See an example below:

```
import unittest

class MyTestClass1(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
         pass

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        pass

    def test1(self):
         pass

    # lots of tests

class MyTestClass2(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
         pass

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        pass

    def test1(self):
         pass

    # another whole lot of tests


if __name__=="__main__":
    # add your global initialization code here
    global_initialization()

    # MyTestClass1 initialization:
    MyTestClass1.setUpClass() # python 2.7 only

    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(MyTestClass1)
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)

    # MyTestClass1 initialization:
    MyTestClass2.setUpClass() # python 2.7 only

    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(MyTestClass2)
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

The `unittest` [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html) has some other examples of similar use which could be of assistance.

**Edit:** Unbeknown to me until this moment, it seems that Python 2.7 has a  `setUpClass()`, (should be a class method, hence the decorator) which seems to do what you need it to . However, that's not the case in Python 2.6 and you should provide your own initialization routines.

Comment: Hi mindcorrosive, thx for your posting. This is really a nice way of doing this, but my question was specifically about the PyUnit functionality of the PyDev plugin. Using PyUnit somehow the main is does not get called. So any initialization in there would not be executed. Maybe PyUnit is not the best way to use unit-testing but maybe it does support some initialization functionalities?!