# Python Unittest with different inputs

Tags: python, unit-testing

I want to apply the same unittest to different inputs and outputs.
For instance:

```py
def test_something(self):
   calculated = some_funtion(input_data[idx])
   self.assertEquals(calculated, expected[idx])
```

for all `idx` (say, 1,000).

[There's this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196376/how-to-write-a-unit-test-where-each-test-case-has-different-input-but-does-the-s) that asks something similar, but the question does not have any satisfactory answers.

I have to use Python `unittest`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must stick with `unittest` and not use the superior `pytest`, I would recomend to use the [parameterized](https://github.com/wolever/parameterized) library.

```
from parameterized import parameterized

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
   @parameterized.expand([1,2,3,...., 100])  # your idxs
   def test_something(self, idx):
       calculated = some_funtion(input_data[idx])
       self.assertEquals(calculated, expected[idx])
```